# opening files of different types in Spring MVC app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a requirement where through one of the JSP files in the spring web app that I am working on,files with different extensions (eg. .pdf, .xls, .txt, etc) need to be opened for viewing purposes.I did see that there is a ContentNegotiatingView Resolver available in the spring API.  Can this be used for my requirement?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about uploading and viewing files in the browser?  Or just displaying static content of different file types?

Comment: Thanks for your response.Basically,the requirement is to read a file from a location and view it either using notepad,wordpad based on the file type.